# RETURN the amount of males and the amount of females in 1 table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to RETURN the amount of  males and the amount of females in 1 table using MySQL. I have created a query that return a tables with males and females rows, but my column is not being populated. its results =0;

Here is my query. I get the table but it doesn't get populated

```
SELECT COUNT(gender) AS 'Female', COUNT(gender) AS 'Male'
FROM customers
WHERE gender = 'female' AND 'male';
```

Any Suggestions,

Comment: `WHERE gender = 'female' AND 'male';` I assume this only works because MySQL is horrendous at adhering to anything resembling an ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: Your WHERE clause will never be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(gender = 'female', 1, 0)) AS 'Female',
  SUM(IF(gender = 'male', 1, 0)) AS 'Male'
FROM customers
```

The IF gets you a value of 1 or 0 depending on whether the gender is female (resp. male) or not, and then you just sum up those zeros and ones to get the overall count.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think to use a IF.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `CASE` statement too:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Female',
    SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Male'
FROM customers
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL equates `true` with `1` and `false` with `0` you can use a shorter version:

```
SELECT
  SUM(gender = 'female') AS `Female`,
  SUM(gender = 'male')   AS `Male`
FROM customers
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e0673/1)